# How to add entities when join table has extra data (payload)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, entity-framework-4.3

(USING ENTITY FRAMEWORK 4.3 CODE FIRST)

The code is below. I want to actually be able to do something like:

```
var instanceStudent = new Student2(){...};
var instanceCourse = new Course2(){...};
instanceStudent.Add(instanceCourse);
db.SaveChanges();
```

...or anything like that, so long as it works. Basically, I currently am a noob at Entity Framework and I want to be able to know how to add an Entity within another Entity while the Junction table has data in it (i know it's easy on an **empty** junction table, but i'm stumped on this one)

```
    public class Student2
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual string StudentName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment2> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Course2
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual string CourseName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Enrollment2> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Enrollment2
    {
        public virtual int StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual string Grade { get; set; }

        public virtual Student2 Student { get; set; }
        public virtual Course2 Course { get; set; }
    }

    public class ManyMany2 : DbContext, IContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student2> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course2> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment2> Enrollments { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Student2>()
                .HasKey(student => student.StudentId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course2>()
                .HasKey(course => course.CourseId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment2>()
                .HasKey(enrollment => new { enrollment.StudentId, enrollment.CourseId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Student2>()
                .HasMany(student => student.Enrollments)
                .WithRequired()
                .HasForeignKey(enrollment => enrollment.StudentId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Course2>()
                .HasMany(course => course.Enrollments)
                .WithRequired()
                .HasForeignKey(enrollment => enrollment.CourseId);
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ManyMany2>());

            var c1 = new Course2() { CourseName = "Spanish" };
            var c2 = new Course2() { CourseName = "Science" };
            var c3 = new Course2() { CourseName = "History" };

            var s1 = new Student2() { StudentName = "JC" };
            var s2 = new Student2() { StudentName = "Joe" };
            var s3 = new Student2() { StudentName = "Jill" };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is Enrollment2.Grade a required field?

Comment: this isn't a real-world project, just me trying EF Code First but I'm stumped... if "required" as in validation requirement? no.

Comment: Please do not preface your code with Entity Framework. That is what tags are for

Comment: @MystereMan i'm just curious why you asked that?

Comment: @JanCarloViray - because I wanted to know if it was necessary to supply Grade when creating an instance of Enrollment2.

Comment: @JanCarloViray - see update for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework does not support direct many-to-many associations if the join table has a payload.  This means you have to do something like this:

```
var instanceStudent = new Student2(){...};     
var instanceCourse = new Course2(){...};
var instanceEnrollment = new Enrollment2() 
      { Course = instanceCourse, Student = instanceStudent };
db.Enrollments.Add(instanceEnrollment);
db.SaveChanges();
```

You could also do (or similar with Courses) the following:

```
var instanceStudent = new Student2(){...};
var instanceCourse = new Course2(){...};
instanceStudent.Enrollments = new Enrollment2() { Course = instanceCourse };
db.Students.Add(instanceStudent);
db.SaveChanges();
```